# Can uncle/orphaned blocks occur on Polygon?

Tags: polygon

As somebody who is familiar with the underlying mechanics of Ethereum, but not familiar with the underlying mechanics of Polygon and their differences from Ethereum, I would like to know whether the classic blockchain scenario of uncle blocks and orphaned blocks can occur on Polygon.

If they can, what is a rule-of-thumb safe amount of blocks to wait in order for the probability of a block becoming orphaned to become negligible?